# Использование диаграммы классов

Tags: uml

Попытался оперативно найти ответ, не получилось! Как на диаграмме классов обозночается, что класс A создаёт обьекты классов В и С ? Это должно быть какое то отношение (стрелка)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На диаграмме классов такие связи не изображаются. Они могут быть изображениы на диаграмме объектов или диаграмме последовательностей. Если вы делаете именно диаграмму классов, то попробуйте выразить это через отношения "ассоциация" или "зависимость". Возможно, если вы приведёте конкретный пример того, над чем вы работаете, вам смогут дать более развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: Скажем треуется изобразить диаграмму классов для windows приложения написанного при использовании MFC + STL + классы собственного сочинения, с целью графической документации проекта. Где можно посмотреть готовый UML проект для какого нибудь не большого приложения?

Comment: Огрубляя: если экземпляр класса А имеет атрибуты типа класс В и класс С, то это отношение агрегации. Если экземпляры B и С не являются составными частями A, то это ассоциация.

Comment: И ещё вопрос - Синглтон Майерса как изобразить? :)
(в том смысле есть ли у него какое то определённое обозначение)

Comment: UML не оперирует такими конкретностями - это абстрактный язык